# PHP Upload Image URL no extension

Tags: php

I need some help on how to do this, I have this URL http://mtv.mtvnimages.com/uri/mgid:uma:content:mtv.com:1698905?width=281&height=211, and I need to upload it via PHP but there is no extension for the URL all the images like this from MTV are .jpg, I know this because I did an upload via URL through imageshack.us and it generated/saved the URL with the extension .jpg.

Comment: Define *upload a URL*, please

Comment: I can't see the problem here.....so what if you don't see the extension directly in url?

Comment: need to have it uploaded/saved via PHP but there is no extension in the URL so thats the issue i am having.

Comment: Please, this is nonsense. The image is on mtvnimages.com. You may want to *download* it from your server... and then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine some combination of

```
$url = 'http://mtv.mtvnimages.com/uri/mgid:uma:content:mtv.com:1698905?width=281&height=211';
$image = file_get_contents($url);
file_put_contents('newimage.jpg', $image);
```

should help

You could also extract the ID from the url too (I assume that it's the ID):

```
$url = 'http://mtv.mtvnimages.com/uri/mgid:uma:content:mtv.com:1698905?width=281&height=211';
preg_match('!(\d+)\?!', $url, $matches);
$image = file_get_contents($url);
file_put_contents($matches[1] . '.jpg', $image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple i guess 
`$uploadurl=" http://mtv.mtvnimages.com/uri/mgid:uma:content:mtv.com:1698905?width=281&height=211".".jpg"`
JUst concat ".jpg" at the end

Comment: The problem with that is it returns an HTTP 500 error, which wont allow the image to save.

Comment: Well thats what you should have posted in your question......edit your question and post real problem...

Comment: its because i think the image is "1698905" if concating in the end that may be the error

Comment: @AnthonyFrancisVasquez A 500 error is a server-side error, simply enable error reporting and give us the error in your question, then we can actually help you..

Comment: It's not on my server, http://mtv.mtvnimages.com/uri/mgid:uma:content:mtv.com:1698905?width=281&height=211.jpg thats where the 500 error is being displayed.

Comment: When i changed the url to 1698905.jpg? i could see the mtv logo. SO i think its there you need to insert the ".jpg"

Comment: I suggest u use explode then use implode .